# Finding $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}} (\sin(x) + \cos(x))$ from the Definition of a Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> By using the definition of a limit, prove that
>   $$ \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \sin(x) + \cos(x) \right) = \sqrt{2}. $$

I tried to factorize in multiplication form and use some inequality theorems to find $|x-c|$ but it was wrong! Please help me.

Comment: Where are your computations?  What have you tried?  Also, it is generally bad form to simply post an image of your question.  Type it out---it makes it easier for search engines to find it.

Comment: Just "plug it in", why do you need the definition here?

Comment: @KSplitX I think that's probably the assignment.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thank you so much! Because I don't actually know how to type it in the "Stack Exchange"app in phone! ! And I have tried to use the formula of $sin(x) +cos(x)$

Comment: @November ft Blue https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference this explains the basics of typing out mathematical notation and it still works for the app.

Comment: Such a question cannot be answered without a specific definition of the trigonometric functions. Please provide it.

Answer (score 2):

*HINT*

> $$|\cos{x}+\sin{x}-\sqrt{2}|=|\cos{x}+\sin{x}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}|$$ $$=|\cos{x}-\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\sin{x}-\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}|$$ $$\leq|\cos{x}-\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}|+|\sin{x}-\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}|$$

.

> Now we know that : $$\cos{x}-\cos{y}=-2\sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}\sin{\frac{x+y}{2}}$$ $$\sin{x}-\sin{y}=2\sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}\cos{\frac{x+y}{2}}$$ $$\sin{x} \leq |x|$$

Use these and you will have the epsilon-delta proof of your limit.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried your way but I missed the inequality part so my teacher marked it wrong.

Comment: you are welcome..if my answer helped you then you can accept it.

Comment: Yeah it does. I appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

By a shift of the variable and trigonometric identities, you can show that this is equivalent to

$$\lim_{x\to0}\cos x=1.$$

Then you need a proper definition of the cosine, or some relevant property taken for granted (for example, the cosine is a continuous function and $\cos(0)=1$; or $1-\dfrac{x^2}2\le\cos x\le1$).

Comment: Good idea:) thank you , I appreciate it.

Comment: @NovemberftBlue: I would appreciate that you give your definition of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: I had used $|sinf(x)|\le|f(x)|$ if $f(x)->0$ And $|cosf(x)|\le1$ if $f(x)->0$ when I met the multiplication form. Do you agree ?

Comment: @NovemberftBlue  How is $|\cos x|\le 1$ helpful ?

Comment: I think the inequality is used to eliminate $cos x$. Example, when we face the formula of $sin x - sin y $ which equal to $2 sin(\dfrac{x-y}2). cos(\dfrac{x+y}2 )\le 2 .| \dfrac{x-y}2 |. 1 \le |(x-y)| < E$ which $E=a > |x-y| >0$ as an example of $$\lim_{x\to y}\sin x = sin y $$

Comment: @NovemberftBlue: you need a lower bound for squeezing. And you still haven't given a definition of the cosine.

Comment: actually i am not sure what's the definition of Cosine . Can u show me? I will appreciate it.

Comment: @NovemberftBlue: no I can't. I can't guess what your teacher told you.